# Solución al error: “Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3” CORREO CON JAVA Y MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jframe

Mi código funciona y envia 3 correos que están registrados en la base de datos, pero cuando le agrego 2 registros más; es decir: ya tengo 5 correos  en mi base de datos cuando le doy a enviar me sale que hay un error en el array que solo se permiten tres correos y no se como hacer que me cuente los 2 correos mas que ingrese a la base de datos...

Aqui el codigo para ingresar a la base de datos:

```
 try {

        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Connection con = conn.getConexion();

        String sql = "SELECT nombre, email FROM persona";
        String[] correos_destinos = null;

        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rd = rs.getMetaData(); // Obtenemos el metadata desde el resulset
            int filas = rd.getColumnCount();
            correos_destinos = new String[filas +1];
            int indice = 0;

            while (rs.next()) {
                correos_destinos[indice] = rs.getString("email");
                indice++;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(envio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

**CÓDIGO EMAIL**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

**CÓDIGO SESSION**

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
```

**CÓDIGO MENSAJE**

```
String correoRemitente = "ingresar correo";
String passRemitente = "ingresar contraseña";
String asunto = "PRUEBA V3";
String mensaje = "PITO!!<br><b>By Takeshi Jeff...</b>";
```

**CODIGO CONSTRUCCIÓN DEL MENSAJE**

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correoRemitente));

        Address[] receptores = new Address[correos_destinos.length];
        int j = 0;
        while (j <= correos_destinos.length) {
            receptores[j] = new InternetAddress(correos_destinos[j]);
            j++;
        }
```

**CÓDIGO RECEPTOR**

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receptores);
message.setSubject(asunto);
message.setText(mensaje, "ISO-8859-1", "html");

Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
t.connect(correoRemitente, passRemitente);
t.sendMessage(message, 
message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

**CIERRE DE CONEXIÓN**

```
 t.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correo Electronico Enviado");

    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(envio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(envio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**AQUI ESTA EL ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at app.envio.btnMasivoActionPerformed(envio.java:88)
at app.envio.access$000(envio.java:24)
at app.envio$1.actionPerformed(envio.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**BD**
[image: BD]

Tal y como dije el error debería estar en la conexión a la base de datos, cuando estoy trayendo los metadatas; específicamente en el while, creo que estoy cogiendo las columnas que son 3 y cojo 3 registro de filas.

Comment: Hola! Por favor, no uses mayúscula sostenida, que acá no se permite porque se entiende como si estuvieras gritando. Edita tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: PD. No se sabe de dónde sale la variable `correos_destinos`. Tu ejemplo es difícil de diagnosticar porque no está completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo tu problema se encuentra en la línea:

```java
int filas = rd.getColumnCount();
```

Estás tomando el número de columnas como si fueran la cantidad de registros devueltos. Para superar este problema haz lo siguiente:

1 - Reemplaza estas líneas:

```java
ResultSetMetaData rd = rs.getMetaData(); // Obtenemos el metadata desde el resulset

int filas = rd.getColumnCount();
correos_destinos = new String[filas + 1];
int indice = 0;
```

Por una nueva definición de `correos_destinos` como  lista:

```java
List<String> correos_destinos= new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Nota:** tienes que importar estas clases que están en `Java.util`.

2 - El `while` debe quedar así:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
  correos_destinos.add(rs.getString("email"));
}
```

3 - Haz lo mismo con receptores: le cambias a `List<Address>`:

```java
List<Address> receptores = new ArrayList<Address>();

for(String correo : correos_destinos) {
  receptores.add( new InternetAddress(correo) );
}
```

4 - Antes de agregar los receptores al mensaje conviertes la lista a array

```java
Address[] receps = new Address[receptores.size()];
receps = receptores.toArray(receps);
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receps);
```

Y con ello, ya no deben haber problemas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103551/discussion-on-answer-by-juan-carlos-guibovich-solucion-al-error-exception-in-t).